# "I got married" and "I have got married"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, british-english, adjective-phrases, conjugations

I know" I got married" could means "I was married" or "I became married but could it also mean **"I have been married"**?

Similarly, I know "I have got married" means I have become married" but could it also mean "**I have been married"**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of those phrases mean, "I did the ceremony where I became legally married."

The ones in simple past don't mean anything else.

The ones in present perfect *also* mean there's some connection between that past event and the present, though without context, it's impossible to say what that connection is. It could be that they're still married, or that they have the experience of doing that ceremony, or they have the experience of being someone's spouse, or anything else that you can infer about someone who has been through that ceremony, given the right context.

Comment: so "I have got married" could also refer to "I have been married" am i interpreting right?

Comment: @Southman if i replace "marriade/adjective" with "painted/verb" and make a sentence as in "Room has got painted" then do you not think here "has got" could mean "has been" as in has been painted or "has become painted"?

Comment: @BilalZafar Technically, yes, though as others have mentioned, that phrase doesn't sound natural, and many would say it's incorrect. Also, you responded to Southman in the wrong answer. Please move your comment to the other answer.

Comment: could you pls tell me which sentence you are referring to in terms of "have been" for "have got". Room has got painted or I have got married?

Comment: how could i move the comment to answer section. I am afraid I am unable to find option for that :(

Comment: @BilalZafar I meant delete the comment, and write it again :)

Comment: my mistake, i could not understand in the first place

Comment: my last query pls.As earlier you said that for "I have got married" it could mean " I have been sick" but it won't sound natural Just in case if change the phrase and say "I have got sick" will the interpretion will be ok as in "i have been sick" (though "I have become sick is obviously correct)

Comment: I never said that "I have got married" could mean "I have been sick". Many would jokingly agree there's a connection between the two, but I'd never say that while trying to help someone learn English. I don't understand your question

Comment: Alas. Yes you are right. I Apologise that what typo.my last query pls. As earlier you said that for "I have got married" it could mean " I have been married" but it won't sound natural  but just in case if change the phrase and say "I have got sick" will the interpretion be ok as in "I have been sick" (though "I have become sick is obviously correct)

Comment: @BilalZafar "I have got" will always sound unnatural without a *noun* after it. "Married" and "sick" are both adjectives, so neither will ever sound natural. "I have *gotten* married/sick/etc" is fine and natural.

Comment: so could i interpret "I have gotten sick" and "I have gotten married" as in "I have been sick" and "I have been married"? (Though they both definitely interpret the meaning as in "I have become married" and "I have become sick")

Comment: @BilalZafar Yes, it's possible for them to mean that. Of course, **Context is King**, so they'll mean what makes sense for the context. Normally, "I've gotten sick" means "I'm sick right now", but it *could* mean "I have been sick (at some time in my life)."

Comment: thanks for keepying me in loops. I am totally clear now :)

Answer (score 2):

"I have got married" sounds wrong to me as a native English speaker.

"I have gotten married" sounds more natural, though still awkward.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/have-got-and-have

It looks like "I have got" should only be used to describe ownership of a noun, for example: "I've got an apple in my bag."
("I've" is the same as "I have", just contracted.)

I would not place a verb participle after "have got." For example "I have got dismissed" sounds wrong to me, and does not appear acceptable in the dictionary link either.

Comment: as though you said "I have gotten married is natural but still awkward but could i interpret " I have gotten married" as " I have been married" other than " I have become married". Similarly could we interpret " I got married" as " I have been married" other than "I became married"?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: I wanted to know whether "got"  could mean "became" or "been/have been" and "have gotten could mean "have become" or ,"i have been"?

–

Comment: _Gotten_ is only natural in American English. The only context in which _I have got married_ sounds natural would be in answer to the question "What have you been doing recently?"

Answer (score 1):

''I have got married'' indicates you are still married. "I have been married" indicates you're not married but I still wouldn't say it that way. The ideal would be ''I've been married for 'x' years.

Comment: @sothman but do you not think "have got" could  be transformed into "have been"? As gotube mentioned that "have got married" could mean someone has an experience of being someone's spouse.

Comment: @Bilal Zafar Can't buddy. ''I have got married'' is in the present perfect indicating the action (the act of getting married) took place in the past but still has effects in the present.

Comment: @Southmanthanks and how about " I got married" as in " i have been married"?

Comment: @Bilau Zafar As a suggestion, it would be better if you study the concept of verb tenses in your language and then look at what their equivalence would be in English, but always within a context. It's the best I can do to help you, friend. English is not an exact science.

Comment: i appreciate :)